# How to change RoutingUrl for MVC application in case of single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.

I have the routingUrl as **http://myapp/Home/Products/Productname/DocTypename/CountryName** Now i am trying to make the url as **http://myapp/Products/Productname/DocTypename/CountryName**

As I have only one controller, I want to get rid of **Home** directory from the Url.

Here is my code in Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
    { 
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); 

        routes.MapRoute( 
            "Default", // Route name 
            "{controller}/{action}/{ProductName}/{DocTypename}/{CountryName}", // URL with parameters 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", ProductName = UrlParameter.Optional, DocTypename = UrlParameter.Optional, CountryName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
        ); 
}
```

Here ProductName/DocTypename/CountryName are dynamic.

I am getting the below error when i don't specify controller in the above code:

The RouteData must contain an item named 'controller' with a non-empty string value.

Appreciate your time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this route, but make sure  its before the default route..

```
 routes.MapRoute( 
            "Default", // Route name 
            "{action}/{ProductName}/{DocTypename}/{CountryName}", // URL with parameters 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Products", ProductName = UrlParameter.Optional, DocTypename = UrlParameter.Optional, CountryName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
        );
```